# Spring boot how to use a server.xml with embedded tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, datasource, server.xml

I work on a project where I have two ways to deploy my app.
First with a tomcat non-embedded that have a server.xml file and that work perfectly.
Or with an embedded one, that I try to pass a server.xml file with the same configuration but it's not working.
The goal is to use the jndi name to configure the datasource

Like this :

```
@Value("${hibernate.connection.datasource}")
private String jndiName;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    log.info("Creating datasource");
    try {
        return new JndiTemplate().lookup(jndiName, DataSource.class);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        log.error("Technical issue on datasource configuration", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Does anyone has an idea to resolve the issue ?

**UPDATE**

The previous code was deleted

properties file :

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDB
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql: ect...
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
```

Comment: Why? imho you are solving this in the wrong way. When using embedded tomcat don't use JNDI just use a spring configured datasource (by specifying the `spring.datasource` properties and you really shouldn't be using the `hibernate.connection` properties for production, as recommended by the hibernate team themselves). When having JNDI just override the configuration and specify the `spring.datasource.jndi-name` property to have the JNDI configuration enabled.

Comment: @M.Deinum If i understand well I have to Autowire a datasource field in my java configuration class then deal with properties keys ? And spring will use jndiName if I specified spring.datasource.jndi-name key or other connection properties if I specified spring.datasource keys instead

Comment: No you don't... Spring will configure the datasource depending on the properties set. You are using Spring Boot work with it, not around it :)

Comment: ok understood !! :) it's working well with my embedded tomcat with the properties url, username, password. But when I setup the property spring.datasource.jndi-name for my non-embedded tomcat it's not working (spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDB). Do you know why spring is not  working with my properties file ?

Comment: What isn't working? You don't need any code, just configuration (so you should remove the JNDI lookup you are doing now. And you should use or jdni-name or the other properties but not both.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes sure, I deleted my java code, if I use the JNDI name property I don't use the other ones and If I use url, username, password I don't use JNDI name. It's working well with url, username, password on embedded tomcat but not with JNDI name on installed tomcat

Comment: Doesn't it do the lookup or is something else happing? Do you have H2 included ?

Comment: Yes it doesn't do the lookup, H2 included and available in my maven dependencies

Comment: You might want to remove the H2 dependency (assuming you are using it for testing only) as it might trigger embedded over JNDI.

Comment: I did but same issue spring don't seems to lookup at the jndi name property. I was able to do a conditional datasource depends on the server I run but I'm not using the power of spring-boot :(

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: I didn't setup any version so it should take the more recent one

Comment: Euh... You should have specified at least a version some where....

Comment: Yes it's 1.3.7 RELEASE